# Session array is empty

Tags: php, session

This is more of a general question without specific code.
Under what circumstances can a `$_SESSION` variable in PHP simply vanish?

I have properly declared

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

without spaces at the very top of each page. On one page, I can refer to the session variable and everything's OK. Yet, when I go to the page that's a problem, and use

```
<pre> <?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>  </pre>
```

I get no results - the session is empty.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: any include later on in the file?

Comment: We need to see more code from the problem file.

Comment: Are you somehow overwriting the $_SESSION variable along the way? either by an unset() or an assignment?

Comment: Figured it out. bad `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. It had to do with the fact that there was a problem `<body>` tag (and `/body`) in the wrong place. Once moved/removed, it works.